# Can I access my phone images from an other mobile on remote?

Tags: android, remote-access

I have two android phones and I want to access to the phone images from one to the other. 
Is it possible using android? 
If yes, how to do it?
The images in the android device are stored under a local URI, I dont know how to make them accessible on remote.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can install ftp client in one device and server in other device and then enable ftp server so that you can access from other device